# Cos'è un "foro di abbrivio"?

Tags: meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *Gioco del matto soto la croce* (o *I crozadór*) di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> PRIMO INCHIOVATORE    
>   E io in quest'altra. Buttatemi un chiodo lungo, che il martello ce l'ho di mio. Oh che chiodaccio! Scommettete che in sette martellate lo picchio dentro tutto? 
>   
>   SECONDO INCHIOVATORE    
>   E io ce la farò in sei, vuoi scommettere? 
>   CAPO INCHIOVATORI    
>   D'accordo. Forza, allargatevi voi 
>   due che gli mettiamo le ali a questo angiolotto [cosí] che possa volare come Icaro nel cielo. 
>   (*Pausa*). Tiriamo insieme... Insieme, ho detto!... Me lo rovesciate! Piano che deve restare in mezzo della sella il cavaliere... Un 
>   po' di piú verso me... bene, sono sul segno... proprio nel buco. (*Indica il **foro di abbrivio** già approntato nella 
>   tavola*).

Ho cercato il vocabolo "abbrivio" in parecchi dizionari e ho visto che può essere anche scritto "abbrivo". Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cos'è un "foro di abbrivio". Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dalla definizione di ***[abbrivo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/abbrivo/)*** (o abbrivio, [sono ammesse entrambe le forme](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/abbrivo-o-abbrivio_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)) del vocabolario Treccani

> **abbrivo** (o **abbrìvio**) s. m. [der. di *abbrivare*.] – Impulso iniziale
>   con cui si dà moto o si aumenta gradualmente la velocità di una nave,
>   di un’imbarcazione, e per estens. di altro veicolo; anche la quantità
>   di moto che la nave o il veicolo ha nel momento in cui cessa l’azione
>   dei mezzi propulsivi; sono soprattutto usate le locuz. *dare l’a.* e
>   *prendere* o *pigliare l’a.*: *dare l’a. a un carrello; il motoscafo ha
>   preso l’abbrivo*. In senso fig., riferito a persona, *prendere l’a.*,
>   prendere l’aire, iniziare con slancio un’azione (e spec. a parlare, a
>   scrivere, a operare), in modo da proseguire per la forza stessa
>   dell’impeto iniziale: *Perpetua, preso l’abbrivo nel parlare di
>   matrimoni, non la finiva più* (Manzoni).

esso indica l'inizio del movimento.

In senso figurato riferito a persona indica l'inizio di un'azione, mentre nei riferimenti alle cose, come ad esempio in questo caso, indica un foro creato nella tavola per facilitare l'inserimento successivo del chiodo.

Un po' come quando si deve appendere un quadro al muro e si tiene il chiodo con le dita; solitamente il primo colpo è più leggero e crea un minuscolo foro (di abbrivio) per fare in modo che il chiodo stesso venga retto dal muro così da poter dare colpi di martello più forti successivamente.

Come fa giustamente notare @RiccardoDeContardi esiste anche l'espressione ***foro pilota*** che può indicare

> Praticare correttamente un [foro pilota](https://www.wikihow.it/Praticare-un-Foro-Pilota) con il trapano è un’abilità
>   essenziale in falegnameria. Si tratta di un piccolo foro che viene
>   utilizzato come guida per inserire una vite nel legno.

sia in ambito edilizio

> 6.1.4 Indagini geognostiche per scavo previo [foro pilota](https://books.google.it/books?id=UoDvqSd4yp8C&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=foro%20pilota&source=bl&ots=bGXUz4MkHf&sig=bZzYxTgr9Ym5puuPCGcdeUy2IX4&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQx5DKk-TYAhWMfFAKHR3vDcgQ6AEISDAH#v=onepage&q=foro%20pilota&f=false) La realizzazione mediante fresa ad attacco integrale di un foro pilota di
>   piccolo diametro, coassiale allo scavo della futura galleria, è legata
>   a scelte che possono essere fondamentalmente distinte in due ordini:
>   1. realizzazione del foro pilota come mezzo d'opera; ...

Comment: mi pare si chiami anche foro pilota ma non sono sicuro, potrei sbagliarmi